# insufficient storage on htc

Tags: insufficient-memory

I recently purchased an HTC Desire 510 ever since I got it I have had issues with not having enough space. I had a 5gig SD card that I was using and it still seemingly wasn't enough space even though I had almost nothing installed on the phone and had almost no pictures or videos or anything else. So I went and picked up a 32gig SD card thinking this would solve my problem. I switched my storage settings to have my SD card as my primary storage source. I know my phone is reading the card because it shows up and it shows me how much space is left but when I went to install something my phone still told me "insufficient storage". I'm getting frustrated because I don't know what else to try and correct this problem. Help?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from the **[insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)** tag?